# asymptote.sty not found

Tags: asymptote

Running a sample code with `\usepackage{asymptote}`, I get `asymptote.sty` not found. I have installed ProTeXt which installed MikTeX 2.9. Now, to resolve this issue, I installed `asypictureb` package the definiton given as `User-Friendly Integration of Asymptote into LaTeX` by MikTeX Package Manager (I couldn't find a package named asymptote). Even after installation and rebuilding the system, I get the same error. What should I do?

The Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}[width=10cm,height=10cm]
import three;

currentprojection=perspective(300,-650,500,center=true);


// define two types of ions
surface iona = scale3(20)*unitsphere;
surface ionb = scale3(25)*unitsphere;

// surface properties and color of the ions
material White = material(diffusepen=gray(0.4),emissivepen=gray(0.6));
material Red = material(diffusepen=red,emissivepen=lightred);

// style of lines connecting ions
pen thick=linewidth(2);

for(int x=-1; x<2; ++x) {
  for(int y=-1; y<2; ++y) {
    for(int z=-1; z<2; ++z) {
      draw(shift(100*(x,y,z))*iona,White);
    }
  }
}

for(int x=-1; x<2; ++x) {
  for(int y=-1; y<2; ++y) {
    for(int z=-1; z<2; ++z) {
      if(x<1) draw(100*(x,y,z)--100*(x+1,y,z),thick);
      if(y<1) draw(100*(x,y,z)--100*(x,y+1,z),thick);
      if(z<1) draw(100*(x,y,z)--100*(x,y,z+1),thick);
    }
  }
}

for(int x=-1; x<2; x+=2) {
  for(int y=-1; y<2; y+=2) {
    for(int z=-1; z<2; z+=2) {
      draw(shift(50*(x,y,z))*ionb,Red);
    }
  }
}
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post the sample code you are using? Include everything, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also, note that the `asypictureB` package uses different code from the `asymptote` package; in particular, if you're using `asypictureB`, you should include the line `\usepackage{asypictureB}` but not the line `\usepackage{asymptote}`. (Full disclosure: I am the author of `asypictureB`.)

Comment: One final note: Neither package will work unless you have installed the Asymptote software. This happens automatically with TeXLive, but with MikTeX, you need to install it manually. At a minimum, you can probably do this by running the `asymptote-2.27-setup.exe` file from [this website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asymptote/files/2.27/). For a less minimal solution, follow the link in Joseph Wright's comment.

Comment: @CharlesStaats please see my edited question

Comment: Tried putting asymptote into your document folder? LaTeX looks there too.

Comment: One thing that may help is adding the line `settings.prc=false;` just before `import three`. In any case, the specific error you are getting is likely to be fixed by following the installation instructions in the answers linked to by Joseph Wright.

Comment: Due to a lack of feedback to the last comment, i vote to close as duplicate of @JosephWright's comment.